# How to generate seasonal component forecast from statsmodels.tsa.x13 in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels, forecast

I'm trying to get the seasonal component forecast from the statsmodels.tsa.x13.

In statsmodels.tsa.x13.x13_arima_analysis I set the forecast_period=60. As default the code does not return seasonal component forecast as a separate object (see
https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.x13.x13_arima_analysis.html?highlight=x13).

I modified the the x13.py code to be able to extract historical d10 (seasonal component numbers from spec). However I don't know how to extract the forecast of this component.

Maybe there is any other way to calculate seasonality based on the initial time series? I need to calculate d10 (seasonal component with forecast) and d11(seasonaly adjusted time series)